# Typescript class with default values, how to parse JSON to this

Tags: json, typescript

I have a class of type `A`. 
This class has several properties, let's call them `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3`.

When I'm calling an `API`, that returns a `JSON` string representing the object, some properties might be omitted if they are null. Further down the road, however, this object is used to construct a form dynamically (using `Formik`, but that's unrelated).
This framework expects all properties to be there, and some will be visible dynamically depending on other properties.

So my question, how can I parse a `JSON` response to my custom class, keeping default values in case properties are omitted in the `API` response?

What I've tried was:

```
static getCustomer(id) {
        return fetch(process.env.MD_API_URL + 'customers/' + id, { mode: 'cors' })
            .then(response => {
                let cust = new Customer();
                return response.json().then(x => cust = JSON.parse(x));
        }).catch(error => {
            return error;
        });
    }
```

But this returns undefined. Must be doing something wrong...

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since typescript is not actually compiled but translated into javascript so **all the javascript rules apply**.

Therefore deserializing json wont actually create a new instance of the class in question but gives you an object you can "call" `Customer` during design time.

you could however create an object and then assign the json values like this:

```
export class Customer {

   public id: number;
   public name: string;

   // your stuff here
   public myDefaultProp: string = "default value";

   public constructor(init?: Partial<Customer>) {
      Object.assign(this, init);
   }
}
```

your return then would look like this:

```
return response.json().then(x => new Customer(JSON.parse(x)));
```

added an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-16wlmg

Comment: Thanks! I didn't need to explicitly parse as it was already a valid JSON object, so the end result was:

static getCustomer(id) {
        return fetch(process.env.MD_API_URL + 'customers/' + id, { mode: 'cors' })
            .then(response => {
                return response.json().then((x) => { return new Customer(x) })
        }).catch(error => {
            return error;
        });
    }

Thanks!

Comment: This looks great. I'm new to typescript, would you be able to show an example that uses the default values in instance where the item returns as null please?

Answer (score 0):

This essentially just a matter of determining what to do in order to create an instance of a class, and map the properties of a JSON response towards your custom class, and there could be many different ways to solve this,

But I think ([Factory function](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/factory-functions-typescript.aspx)) is appropriate approach for this kind of task.